# Getting error while installing phabricator on centos 6

Tags: apache, centos6, phabricator

I am trying to install Phabricator on Centos, I have followed all steps of installation, but I am getting `Request parameter '__path__' is not set. Your rewrite rules are not configured correctly.`

Bellow is the virtual host entries.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin test@test.com
ServerName phabricator.test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapps/phabricator/webroot/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
ErrorLog logs/phabricator.test.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/phabricator.test.com-access_log common
<Directory "/var/www/html/myapps/phabricator/webroot/">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This config looks old. See https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/ for most up to date config examples.

Comment: @Chad Little mine apache version is 2.2.5, for this version above configuration given in installation manual, but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
```

I just kept above line in virtual host. Have removed following lines and restarted apache. Its working now for me.

```
RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running phabricator on a centos7 system with apache 2.4.6.

You could use something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mycert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mykey.pem

        ServerName phabricator.myside.local
        ServerAlias hostname.myside.local

        # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it
        # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.
        #
        # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!
        DocumentRoot /opt/phabricator/webroot

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
                RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
        </IfModule>

        <Directory "/opt/phabricator/webroot">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ## mod_php5 directives
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_admin_flag  engine                  On
                php_value       upload_max_filesize     256M
                php_value       post_max_size           256M
                php_value       output_buffering        16384
                php_admin_value date.timezone           'Europe/Berlin'
                php_value       include_path            '.:/opt/PHPExcel/Classes/'
                php_value       memory_limit            256M
                php_value       always_populate_raw_post_data -1

        </IfModule>

        <LocationMatch "\.(?i:os)$">
                ForceType application/octet-stream
                Header set Content-Disposition attachment
        </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Reduce the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` depending on your needs. We had some big binaries nested in the git repositories, so we had to increase it :)